# Shallow render a React/Enzyme component that uses Refs

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jsx, enzyme

I have a React component that I'm testing with Enzyme, that for examples sake looks like this:

```jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.showContents = this.showContents.bind(this)
  }

  showContents() {
    this.button.classList.toggle("active")
    this.button.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show")
    this.props.onRequestShowContents()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <button ref={(ref) => this.button = ref} onClick={this.showContents}>Click to view contents</button>
        <div className="panel">
          {this.props.contents}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Foo
```

I am writing some unit tests using Mocha/Chai/Enzyme and I want to simulate the button press to check my props func gets called.

My basic Enzyme test looks like this:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Foo from '../components/Foo'
import chai from 'chai'
import expect from 'expect'
var should = chai.should()

function setup() {
  const props = {
    onRequestShowContents: expect.createSpy(),
    contents: null
  }

  const wrapper = shallow(<Foo {...props} />)

  return {
    props,
    wrapper
  }
}

describe('components', () => {
  describe('Foo', () => {
    it('should request contents on button click', () => {
      const { props, wrapper } = setup()
      const button = wrapper.find('button')
      button.props().onClick() //this line causes the error
      props.onRequestShowContents.calls.length.should.equal(1)
    })
  })
})
```

Is there any way I can tweak the test or my component code to avoid an error when `this.button` is accessed in the click handler? I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined".

I want keep this as a shallow rendering unit test and don't want to deep render this component with mount, which would require the use of a browser-like env such as jsdom.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's impossible.

Shallow rendering [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) haven't documentation for `ref` property. But mount rendering [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) have it.

Also, you can check this [github issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/316).

In my opinion, to not use mount rendering, instead of accessing `classList` and `nextElementSibling`, set corresponding state variable and display needed classNames depending on this variable.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'm using Redux for state management, so I could probably build the correct list of classes in my higher order react-redux `connect()` component. I'll give that a whirl thanks.

Comment: @Michael, I think for this purpose you can have local state, even you are using redux. Ex. `this.state = { isVisible = false }`, then when you click a `button`, toggle this state variable and in `render` function depending on this variable display corresponding class.

Comment: I'd like to keep this a stateless presentational component, so I can pass in a `show` prop that is managed from above and then display the correct class(es) as a result inside the component based on `this.props.show`.